# MySQL Filtering Attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce

I am trying to create a better way of filtering items on a website.  The actual filtering is working great but displaying the available options has stumped me.

I am using this sql query to get all the options for a specific category.

```
SELECT 
atr1.`type` , atr1.`value`
FROM 
`index-shop-filters` AS atr1 
JOIN 
`index-shop-filters` as atr2 ON atr1.`item` = atr2.`item`  
WHERE 
( atr2.`type` = 'sys-category' AND atr2.`value` = '1828' ) 
GROUP BY 
atr1.`type`, atr1.`value`
```

But when I add a selected filter in the hope to get the remaining filters available.  It doesn't give me the remaining filters.  Instead it ignores the second OR statement.

```
SELECT 
atr1.`type` , atr1.`value`
FROM 
`index-shop-filters` AS atr1 
JOIN 
`index-shop-filters` as atr2 ON atr1.`item` = atr2.`item`  
WHERE 
( atr2.`type` = 'sys-category' AND atr2.`value` = '1828' ) 
OR ( atr2.`type` = 'Manufacturer' AND atr2.`value` = 'Sony' )
GROUP BY 
atr1.`type`, atr1.`value`
```

I tried adding the HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 but that doesn't get the correct results.

The data in the index-shop-filters is like this.

item,type,value

the types are sys-category, manufacturer, size, color, etc.

When they select the first option (like sys-category) it will then display the available options.  If they then select manufacturer (like sony) it will then display the available options that the items are sony, and in the category.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you show us some sample data and explain what results you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I edited the post that said "It doesn't work".

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're saying that adding ``OR ( atr2.`type` = 'Manufacturer' AND atr2.`value` = 'Sony' )`` did not return any extra rows, but you think it should. What if you ONLY search for Sony products? That is, what if your entire `WHERE` clause is ``WHERE ( atr2.`type` = 'Manufacturer' AND atr2.`value` = 'Sony' )`` -- do you then get any data? If not, there is your problem.

Comment: Yep I get all the options with items that manufacturer = Sony.  It works perfectly if only one option is passed.  fyi I added more info at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Why are you joining the same table?

Comment: +rene the reason for joining the same table is so I can get the options available with those settings.  When I don't, the only results that are display is "Manufacturer = Sony, or Cat = 1828" Instead of getting "Color, Size, etc."  I am open to better ideas.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Your updated post makes it sound like you want `AND` instead of `OR`. Are you looking for items in category 1828 **and** that are made by Sony?

Comment: +ean5533 I am looking for items that have the cat 1828 and are made by sony.  Once it finds that then what are the other available options. Which would give the different Sony TV Sizes, etc. When I changed that to AND.  All I get is 2 rows.  One for the cat = 1828 and the other man = sony.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I finally understand what you're trying to do: you aren't trying to get a list of *items*, you're trying to get a list of *item filters*. Sorry, I should have picked up on that sooner.

Anyway, now I understand the problem, but I don't have a great answer. What you're trying to do is fairly complicated, and it can't be done with just one join (as far as I know). I can only think of two ways to do this: with multiple subqueries or with multiple joins. Both of these solutions are complicated and do not scale well, but it's all I can think of.

Here is one possible solution, using subqueries, that I **do not** recommend:

```
SELECT item, `type`, `value`
FROM `index-shop-filters` AS f
WHERE f.item IN (SELECT item FROM `index-shop-filters` WHERE `type` = 'sys-category' AND `value` = '1828')
AND f.item IN (SELECT item FROM `index-shop-filters` WHERE `type` = 'Manufacturer' AND `value` = 'Sony')
```

Here is a solution, using joins, that is **better** but still **not great**:

```
SELECT item, `type`, `value`
FROM `index-shop-filters` AS f
JOIN `index-shop-filters` AS f2 ON f.item = f2.item AND f2.`type` = 'sys-category' AND f2.`value` = '1828'
JOIN `index-shop-filters` AS f3 ON f.item = f3.item AND f3.`type` = 'Manufacturer' AND f3.`value` = 'Sony'
```

And that's all I've got. Both of those solutions should work, but they won't perform well. Hopefully someone else can come up with a clever, scalable answer.

Comment: Great thanks ean5533 for brainstorming this with me.  Yes it's pretty complicated and I have been trying many solutions over the years.  Each is better, but one that doesn't need a cached results is the goal of this project.  You cleared up my confusion.  Now I have my fingers crossed that someone can take your concept to the goal.